# How to identify pod eviction policy?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a Kubernetes cluster deployed on GCP with a single node, 4 CPU's and 15GB memory. There are a few pods with all the pods bound to the persistent volume by a persistent volume claim. I have observed that the pods have restarted automatically and the data in the persistent volume is lost.

After some research, I suspect that this could be because of the pod eviction policy. When I used kubectl describe pod , I noticed the below error.

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were not ready, 1 node(s) were out of disk space, 1 node(s) were unschedulable.
```

The restart policy of my pods is "always". So I think that the pods have restarted after being resource deprived.

How do I identify the pod eviction policy of my cluster and change it? so that this does not happen in the future

Answer (score 2):

> pod eviction policy of my cluster and change

These thresholds ( pod eviction)  are flags of **kubelet**, you can tune these values according to your requirement. you can edit the kubelet config file, here is the detail [config-file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/#start-a-kubelet-process-configured-via-the-config-file)

[Dynamic Kubelet Configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/) allows you to edit these values in the live cluster

> The restart policy of my pods is "always". So I think that the pods have restarted after being resource deprived.

Your pod has been **rescheduled** due to node's issue (not enough disk space ).

> The restart policy of my pods is "always".

It means if the pod is not up and running then  try to **restart** it .